# Is the Wheel of Pain a grinding mill or a torture device?

Tags: conan, conan-the-barbarian-1982

Is the Wheel of Pain a grinding mill or a torture device?

It is after all The Wheel of "Pain". Looking at the footage it's hard to say if there is a lower level where the grind stone would be. Also looks like the middle of nowhere and there is little evidence of storage or means of transportation.

If you have a canon answer I'd be interested to know if it pre\post the movie.

---

Related question from Movies.SE: [Was the Wheel of Pain actual or allegorical?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/402/was-the-wheel-of-pain-actual-or-allegorical)

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/402/was-the-wheel-of-pain-actual-or-allegorical

Comment: Make that an answer and get a bazillion points for lmfao

Comment: More like a bazillion downvotes for taking the p**s :-) I must admit I didn't read it carefully before posting the link.

Comment: The Movie:SE answer is *awful*.

Comment: @Richard - wall of (un)consciousness

Comment: It's a floor wax - AND a dessert topping.

Comment: I choose to think positively and believe it can be both.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The 'Wheel of Pain' is a literal (corn) flour mill.

You can see the flour in the video footage from the film. When the stone turns it's clearly coated in a white powder.

It's described in the [original film script](https://8flix.com/assets/screenplays/c/tt0082198/Conan-the-Barbarian-1982-screenplay-by-John-Milius-%5B3rd-Draft%5D.pdf) thusly;

> **THE WHEEL OF PAIN - EXT MOUNTAIN TOP**
>
> A great wheel of wood, forming **a kind of primitive mill**
> on a frozen plain of rock and Ice. The spokes of the
> wheel are heavy, weather-polished trunks of trees about
> thirty feet long. They are festooned with ice-clotted
> iron chains and manacles.

You can see a local farmer bringing a bag of grain to be milled in the bottom left of Ron Cobb's amazing [concept art](https://johneaves.wordpress.com/2009/04/23/conan-and-cobb/);

[image]

This is all backed up by the film's [official novelisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conan_the_Barbarian_(1982_novel)) which confirms that the wheel is a mill, grinding grain into *corn*flour for making bread.

> Whenever the harvest proved lean, disputes arose among the Vanir. Some wished to reduce the slaves’ rations; others argued that, **if the slaves starved, they could not work the mill wheel, and the whole town would lack for bread. These debates often took place among the townsfolk who brought their corn to be ground**; and no one thought to spare the wretched slaves the furious arguments, since they were deemed too dull or ignorant to understand the spoken word.